# Async recursive method

Tags: c#, asynchronous, recursion, task-parallel-library

Alright...so I'm converting some of my simple-use applications to stop using the backgroundworker system of doing things to standard async. I built a WPF application from scratch using async and it worked brilliantly, so I wanted to convert the rest to do the same (just makes reading the code a bit easier for me). In this case, I use a method to clear out a directory before copying down the files and directories from the machine storing our builds (where they're compiled and deposited). I'm having an issue with the "Empty" method, which I've had to make recursively to function correctly. Here's the method as it currently sits (some things are wrong):

```
public static Task Empty(string targetDir)
    {
        return Task.Run(() =>
            {
                foreach (var directory in Directory.GetDirectories(targetDir))
                {
                    Empty(directory);
                    string[] filelist2 = Directory.GetFiles(directory);
                    foreach (string files in filelist2)
                    {
                        File.SetAttributes(files, FileAttributes.Normal);
                        File.Delete(files);
                    }

                    if (!Directory.EnumerateFileSystemEntries(directory).Any())
                    {
                        Directory.Delete(directory, false);
                    }
                }
                string[] filelist = Directory.GetFiles(targetDir);
                foreach (string files in filelist)
                {
                    File.SetAttributes(files, FileAttributes.Normal);
                    File.Delete(files);
                }
            });
    }
```

Now what this does is delete any files and subdirectories. It worked using the backgroundworker (had no Task or anything in it before), but trying to run in a Task eventually pops up an exception about not being able to find a file. My guess is it has something to do with the threading, but I can't seem to figure out what.

Any ideas what could cause the issue? It fails when it tries to SetAttributes on a file (not the same file every time...just seems once it's recursively looped a number of times it fails to be able to alter the file properties).

Comment: For what it's worth, that's not an async method. It's just a method using TPL.

Comment: @esskar It is there `Empty(directory);`

Comment: Marcel: Since I set the button that initiates it to async and am using awaits on the actual method call itself I figured it was still using asynchronous, but I guess then I'm using TPL. So the reason I'm recursively calling Empty is it was the only way I could seemingly find all files in all subdirectories and delete them before deleting the folders themselves. Any other way I tried didn't delete everything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

wait for the recursion calls

```
public static Task Empty(string targetDir)
{
    return Task.Run(async () =>
        {
            foreach (var directory in Directory.GetDirectories(targetDir))
            {
                await Empty(directory);
                string[] filelist2 = Directory.GetFiles(directory);
                foreach (string files in filelist2)
                {
                    File.SetAttributes(files, FileAttributes.Normal);
                    File.Delete(files);
                }

                if (!Directory.EnumerateFileSystemEntries(directory).Any())
                {
                    Directory.Delete(directory, false);
                }
            }
            string[] filelist = Directory.GetFiles(targetDir);
            foreach (string files in filelist)
            {
                File.SetAttributes(files, FileAttributes.Normal);
                File.Delete(files);
            }
        });
}
```

**EDIT**
There is also lots to improve here.
you are deleting files twice. To fix this, you can reduce the code like

```
public static Task<bool> Empty(string targetDir)
{
    return Task.Run(async () =>
    {
        foreach (var directory in Directory.GetDirectories(targetDir))
        {
            if (await Empty(directory))
                Directory.Delete(directory, false);
        }
        var retval = true;
        foreach (string file in Directory.GetFiles(targetDir))
        {
            try
            {
                File.SetAttributes(file, FileAttributes.Normal);
                File.Delete(file);
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                // something went wrong: log ex
                retval = false;
            }
        }
        return retval;
    });
}
```

but this is still not really performant, since your are still waiting for the recursion calls to return. As @Servy suggested, to many tasks will be created that are useless.
Let me show you a way to do this with only one task.
We define a synchronous function:

```
public static bool Empty(string targetDir)
{
    foreach (var directory in Directory.GetDirectories(targetDir))
    {
        if (Empty(directory))
            Directory.Delete(directory, false);
    }
    var retval = true;
    foreach (string file in Directory.GetFiles(targetDir))
    {
        try
        {
            File.SetAttributes(file, FileAttributes.Normal);
            File.Delete(file);
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            // something went wrong: log ex
            retval = false;
        }
    }
    return retval;    
}
```

and now we define an Async Version of it:

```
public static Task<bool> EmptyAsync(string targetDir)
{
    return Task.Run(() => this.Empty(targetDir));
}
```

this will probably have same/better performance than creates Task with every recusrsion call.

Comment: That was it! You and Brian are perfectly helpful on this. As soon as I read your code I understood what I was doing wrong. When I was debugging I realized it was not waiting for the recursion, but I couldn't figure out how to get it to work correctly (adding await didn't work, but it's because I didn't specify async in the Task.Run). Thanks so much all :)

Comment: This will just go and serialize everything, entirely defeating the purpose of spinning up a whole bunch of tasks.  You might as well just remove all of the asynchronous code and go back to a synchronous algorithm at that point.

Answer (score 3):

It looks you are are deleting the same files twice, and because you are doing it in different threads with each thread enumerating the full list before beginning the delete, you will eventually try to delete a file in one thread that has already been deleted in the other.

Consider files:

/a/1

/a/2

Now consider running your code on folder /.
First you will recurse into /a, which will (in a separate thread) delete the files /a/1 and /a/2 in the loop at the bottom of the method. At the same time you will enumerate the files /a/1 and /a/2 in the loop at the top of the method. One of those will happen before the other, so you will get a FileNotFound from one of them or the other.

Comment: OK that seems to be it. When I'm looking at it the file has already been removed. So would I be right in assuming the reason it's doing this is because backgroundworker did things synchronously, while I'm trying to use async for some of this work? So it's generating both lists of files at the same time, instead of creating the list separately in each loop.

Comment: I think you are confusing separate but related topics of async methods and parallel processing. What you are doing here is parallel processing not async method calls. Async calls are distinguished by having a notification when the called method finishes so the calling thread can retrieve the results.